# Getting string resource from xml file outside onCreate method

Tags: android, android-resources

I am trying to use a `String` from the `string.xml` file as a key in a key-value pair. However when I try to declare the variable before the `onCreate()` method, the program crashes. So if I use the following code I get an error:

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        String MAX_SQUAT = getResources().getString(R.string.max_squat);
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //blah blah blah
    }
    }
```

Whereas when I declare `MAX_SQUAT` inside the `onCreate()` method, there is no problem. I want to declare it outside of `onCreate()` method so I don't need to define it in other methods

Comment: Please add the code and the crash's stack trace

Comment: Sorry, was a little too fast to hit enter. Some code added now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `Context` to get `resources` (as you can see [in the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) `getResources()` is a method of `Context`). Since the `Context` isn't available before `onCreate()`, you can't do this.

You can declare the variable **before** `onCreate()` but you can't initialize it until **after** `onCreate()` has been called.

Ex.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String MAX_SQUAT;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // super call, set content view
        // now you can get the string from strings.xml safely
        MAX_SQUAT = getResources().getString(R.string.max_squat);
    }
```

Declaring it as a member variable this way but initializing it in `onCreate()` will allow you to use it throughout the class and keep it from crashing.

Comment: That'll do it. Thanks!